# HighCharts xAxis label encima do tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Estou tendo um problema, onde o tooltip do gráfico está ficando sempre abaixo do label do xAxis.

Gostaria que o tooltip ficasse por cima do label.

http://jsfiddle.net/toninho09/83gkze29/1/

[image: Highcharts legend encima do tooltip]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende muito do que você quer fazer com a tooltip.

Você pode querer que a *tooltip* siga o *mouse*, por exemplo:

```
tooltip: {
    followPointer: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>'
}
```

Vi que você já estava usando `shared`, que permite que qualquer área do gráfico capture a *tooltip* por meio do movimento do *mouse*.

Você pode usar *positioner* para definir a posição estática/fixa onde a *tooltip* vai ficar:

```
tooltip: {
    positioner: function () {
        return { x: 80, y: 50 };
    }
}
```